# Android UI: black rectangles instead of characters and images

Tags: android, android-design-library

The app is designed for Lollipop (material design) and uses support and design library for back-compatibility. Sometimes it looks weird like this (black rectangles instead of characters, no fab image and button text is absent):

[image]

It's on Xiaomi Mi 3 with android 4.4.4 (with MIUI).
After device reboot it look ok again.

Any idea on what's wrong? Any android design library bug?

Comment: I think Problem With Font

Comment: but what about image looking incorrect? look fab